# Forest package with arrows between nodes

Tags: forest

I am wondering how to add arrows to the `Forest` package syntax tree. I am hoping I don't have to use the Tkiz package to manually draw things. I hope to draw something like this:

[image]

My attempt so far:

```
\begin{forest}
  [
    E [E[T[T [F [digit]]  ][*][F [digit] ]]]
    [+]
    [T [F [digit]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use the decorations library to add a decoration to the edge path? Just an idea; not sure if it would work.

Comment: The forest manual show a few examples of trees with  some arrow.

Comment: give names to nodes and after that draw arrows manually where needed?

Comment: @Fran do you know where I can find the docs?

Comment: @Node.JS Just run `texdoc forest`  i.e., run the program `texdoc` that you have and search the term "forest. In Case that you have not a LaTeX distro installed in the computer (i.e, you are using Overleaf) , there also a texdoc online. Alternatively, you can also search the forest package in CTAN site, and then you will see here a link to the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using the `\draw` command.

```
\begin{forest}
  [
    E, name=11
    [E,name=7 [T, name=6 [T,name=3 [F,name=2 [digit, name=1]]  ][*][F, name=5 [digit, name=4]  ]]]
    [+]
    [T, name=10 [F, name=9  [digit, name=8 ]]]
  ]
  \draw[->,dotted] (1) to[out=west,in=south west] (2);
  \draw[->,dotted] (2) to[out=north west,in=south west] (3);
  \draw[->,dotted] (3) to[out=north west,in=west] (6);
  \draw[->,dotted] (4) to[out=east,in=south east] (5);
  \draw[->,dotted] (5) to[out=north east,in=east] (6);
  \draw[->,dotted] (6) to[out=north west,in=south west] (7);
  \draw[->,dotted] (8) to[out=east,in=south east] (9);
  \draw[->,dotted] (9) to[out=north east,in=south east] (10);
  \draw[->,dotted] (7) to[out=north west,in=west] (11);
  \draw[->,dotted] (10) to[out=north east,in=east] (11);
\end{forest}
```

[image]